# Why I have many numbers after the decimal point with Sum?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a problem to recover a sum of float number.
I have a `Sale` object with a `total` field that is a float.

If I do the sum by hand :

```
>>> sales = Sale.objects.all()
>>> total = 0
>>> for sale in sales:
...     total += sale.total
... 
>>> print(total)
134479.15
```

If I use the ORM Sum:

```
>>> Sale.objects.all().aggregate(ca_total=Sum('total'))['ca_total']
134479.15000000029
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Floating point numbers being slightly inexact?

Comment: Ok so how I can have this result : `134479.15` with the Sum.

Comment: Floating point numbers are often slightly off from what you expect, they do not guarantee accuracy, that's their nature. Floating point numbers should never be compared directly, if the difference between them is small enough they can be considered equal

Comment: @darkvodka: I would advice to work with a `DecimalField`, this will make no rounding errors in the *decimal* number system.

Comment: @darkvodka
round(number, digits)
e.g.: round(134479.15000000029, 2)